# What edition of The Shrinking Man contains a foreword by Stephen King?

Tags: stephen-king, richard-matheson, the-shrinking-man

According to the [Wikipedia article about Stephen King](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stephen_King&oldid=987357155#Influences), one of the author's influences was Richard Matheson, author of *I Am Legend*, *Hell House* and other works. The article claims,

> In a current edition of Matheson's *The Shrinking Man*, King is quoted as saying, "A horror story if there ever was one...a great adventure story—it is certainly one of that select handful that I have given to people, envying them the experience of the first reading."<sup>[citation needed]</sup>

Searching Amazon and [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=ti%3Athe+shrinking+man+au%3Amatheson&qt=advanced&dblist=638) I have been unable to identify that edition. One current edition has appeared in the SF Masterworks series, but the results in WorldCat make no mention of a preface by Stephen King. The 2011 edition by  RosettaBooks does not appear to contain a preface either. The [2001 edition by Gauntlet Publications](https://www.worldcat.org/title/shrinking-man/oclc/262559447?referer=br&ht=edition) has an afterword by David Morell but nothing by Stephen King.

What edition of *The Shrinking Man* contains a foreword or an afterword by Stephen King? Does that text also mention other works by Matheson that influenced King?

Comment: Looking at the length of the quote, it could just be a blurb and not a foreword, possible taken from "Dance Macabre", in which he apparently talks at length about "The Shrinking Man".